# iTunes disable command by trackpad

Tags: itunes, trackpad, shortcut

Since a few months, iTunes is listening to the track-pad fingers command `previous` and `next` (3 fingers swipe) even if it's not the active application (ie: has focus).

This is *extremely* annoying when browsing the web and listening to music. How can I disable this shortcut that I didn't set up ?

I've searched in the trackpad settings, the itTunes ones and the keyboard => shortcuts but didn't find the solution.

BTT screenshot: [image]

Comment: Do You have 3rd party app like **Better Touch Tool** or **Keyboard Maestro**?

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek yes, see screenshot

Comment: So this is the culprit. **Previous** and **Next** refer to track change not going back in browser history.

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek you, Sir, deserve +25 rep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is related with 3rd party app called **Better Touch Tool**. As OP showed on the screenshot - commands **Previous** and **Next** assigned to gestures, refer to Track change in iTunes not going back/forth in browser history.

Comment: You made my day.